# DELPHI WITH JENKINS *.res files not found

Tags: delphi, msbuild

we are  using DELPHI 11 with JENKINS and MSBUILD.
some project showed up with this  strange *.res file  not found error, how to fix ,
where  to change some settings ??

```
error E1026: File not found: 'Dialogs.res' ....
error E1026: File not found: 'Buttons.res' ....
error E1026: File not found: 'Controls.res' .....
error E1026: File not found: 'Dialogs.res' .....
error E1026: File not found: 'Buttons.res' .....
error E1026: File not found: 'FileCtrl.res'.....
```

Comment: Those are all standard RTL/VCL units, it should not be trying to compile any resources for those units. Check your project configuration, make sure it is linking to the standard library binaries and not recompiling RTL/VCL source units directly.

Comment: which setting in the  project config ?   how to adjust

Comment: I can't really answer that definitively. I would start with making sure the RTL/VCL source folders are not present in ANY project settings. And for that matter, the source folders probably shouldn't even be present on a build machine to begin with, since you should never be recompiling the RTL/VCL itself.

Comment: It seems that MSBUILD can't find Delphi LIB folder and its corresponding subfolders which include precompiled standard Delphi units and their corresponding resource files. Typical location of LIB folder is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\lib`.